# System wide mutex in node.js(javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mutex

I wonder if there is a System wide mutex in javascript(*Not an usual mutex with other words*)?

What I have is 2 or more instances of a node.js cmd running.
Those will read and write to the same file and here I don't want them to do that at the exact same time.

The code looks like this:

```js
//Enter Systemwide Mutex here
var textarray = fs.readFileSync("C:/file1.txt").toString('utf-8'); //Read the file
fs.promises.writeFile("C:/file1.txt", "hello"); //Write to file
//Exit Systemwide Mutex here
```

I have made an attempt using the file lock approach(https://www.npmjs.com/package/proper-lockfile) 
I have installed with: "npm i proper-lockfile"
But I receive an error:
**TypeError: lockfile.lock is not a function**

```js
const lockfile = require('C:/myproject/temp/lockfile.txt');

lockfile.lock('C:/myproject/temp/lockfile.txt')
    .then((release) => {
        // Do something while the file is locked

        var textarray = fs.readFileSync("C:/myproject/file1.txt").toString('utf-8'); //Read the file            
        fs.promises.writeFile("C:/myproject/file1.txt", "hello now"); //Write to file
        

        // Call the provided release function when you're done,
        // which will also return a promise
        return release();
    });
```

Comment: Have a look at locking. E.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/proper-lockfile or https://github.com/npm/lockfile

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look on that.

Comment: I have edited my post with the lockfile approach but receives the error: "TypeError: lockfile.lock is not a function". I wonder what could be wrong?

Comment: `require('C:/myproject/temp/lockfile.txt')` → `require('proper-lockfile')`

Comment: Yes you are right, I just noticed that will experiments. I will post an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a working code:

```js
'use strict';
const fs = require('fs');
const lockfile = require('proper-lockfile');

lockfile.lock('C:/myproject/temp/lockfile.txt')
    .then(() => {

        // Do something while the file is locked
        var textarray = fs.readFileSync("C:/myproject/file1.txt").toString('utf-8'); //Read the file
        fs.promises.writeFile("C:/myproject/file1.txt", "hello now"); //Write to file

        // Later..
        return lockfile.unlock('C:/myproject/temp/lockfile.txt');
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do using promise

```
var p_readFile = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    fs.readFile("C:/file1.txt", type, (err, d) => {
        err ? reject(err) : resolve(d);
    });
})

p_readFile.then(function(d){
     console.log(d); 
     //Write Your Write file Syntax Here
     fs.promises.writeFile("C:/file1.txt", "hello");
   })
```

Comment: Is this a system wide mutex. Will it work between 2 different cmd instances? When I run the code, I get: "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: type is not defined"

Comment: ohhhhh that is what you want to do

Comment: I am not sure now, will it work for 2 different instances or only 1? :)